# fedora 26 login loop, not desktop env related

Tags: authentication, fedora-26

I had a power outage during a shutdown and now i cannot login on my main user account ('acnt1' we'll call it). When i click on my acnt1, the screen goes black, then returns to GDM login screen. I am able to startup / login to GNOME with another account('acnt2' we'll call it). I can also log into acnt1 using tty shell (ctrl + alt + f2).

Things I've tried that didn't work:

- renaming /home/acnt1/.config & .gnome (to .config-bak & .gnome-bak)
- installing KDE and using that
- systemctl isolate graphical.target (while in tty)

I realize i could remake the account, and i will if i have to but... im taking this as an opportunity to learn. Any help or ideas you can provide would be very welcome!

log file: https://pastebin.com/JN9mQfEn

This seems to be the error:

> ... audit[3278]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=13 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 pid=3278 comm="bash" exe="/usr/bin/bash" sig=11 res=1
>
> ... kernel: bash[3278]: segfault at 7ffe0e373fe0 ip 000055657844a846 sp 00007ffe0e373fe0 error 6 in bash[556578410000+105000]
>
> ... systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 3444/UID 0).

Extra info: based on that core dump i looked at the logs for the PID. Based on the date, I believe that is when the power outage happened:

`$ journalctl _PID=3444`

> -- Logs begin at Tue 2017-09-19 15:04:59 EDT, end at Mon 2017-11-06  10:18:38 EST. --
> Oct 30 11:59:38 localhost.localdomain gnome-contacts-[3444]: contacts-store.vala:335: Unable to check accounts caps The name org.freedesktop.Telepathy.AccountManager was not provided by any .service files
> Oct 30 11:59:38 localhost.localdomain gnome-contacts-[3444]: backend-store.vala:434: Error preparing Backend 'telepathy': The name org.freedesktop.Telepathy.AccountManager was not provided by any .service files